¿Cómo puedo crear un barchart múltiple?
Tengo una base de datos que contiene varias variables desde el año 2000 hasta 2023, he intentado graficar un barplot que cree una barra para cada variable sin que se superponga,  así:

He intentado de las siguiente maneras:
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.barplot(x='Serie', y=['1. Cuenta corriente','1.03. Bienes y servicios'], data=df, color='salmon',dodge=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.barplot(x='Serie', y='1. Cuenta corriente',hue='1.03. Bienes y servicios', data=df, color='salmon',dodge=True)

Ninguna de estas dos alternativas parece funcionar, alguien con alguna idea que me pueda ayudar a lograrlo??
Muchas gracias!

¿Que contiene la columna Serie? Si hacemos caso a la gráfica ejemplo supongo que los trimestres, si es así ¿en que formato y que tipo de dato?. Lo digo más que nada por si quieres obtener esos dos niveles (año-trimestre) en las etiquetas del eje x.

En este caso, solo quiero graficar los años, los datos están anuales desde 2000 a 2003, la columna que contiene los años se llama Serie y es de tipo Datatime64 :)

En la documentación de Seaborn hay un pequeño ejemplo, Grouped barplots, que muestra como podrías hacerlo y se basa en usar seaborn.catplot().
Lo único es que en nuestro caso deberemos acodar los datos primero para que las variables/columnas a agrupar queden acomodadas en una sola columna (unpivot), para ello se puede usar pandas.DataFrame.melt():
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Serie": pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=24, freq="YE-JAN"),
    "1. Cuenta corriente": [
        2000, 2015, 2400, 2342, 2515, 3000, 3152, 2998, 3200, 3325,
        3700, 3841, 4000, 3251, 3412, 3214, 2825, 3125, 3752, 3245,
        3752, 3584, 3125, 3241],
    '1.03. Bienes y servicios': [
        3251, 3245, 2752, 3025, 2715, 4520, 5152, 5128, 5132, 5325,
        6700, 6841, 6900, 5251, 4412, 4214, 3885, 4125, 4782, 4235,
        3892, 4584, 4125, 4256],
    }
)

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars="Serie", var_name="Variables", value_name="Valor")
melted_df["Serie"] = melted_df["Serie"].dt.year  # Quedarnos solo con el año de cada datetime

sns.catplot(x='Serie', y='Valor', hue='Variables', data=melted_df, kind='bar')
plt.show()


Para ver que hace melt, aquí esta el contenido del dataframe original de ejemplo y el usado para el gráfico tras aplicar melt:
>>> df
        Serie  1. Cuenta corriente  1.03. Bienes y servicios
0  2000-01-31                 2000                      3251
1  2001-01-31                 2015                      3245
2  2002-01-31                 2400                      2752
3  2003-01-31                 2342                      3025
4  2004-01-31                 2515                      2715
5  2005-01-31                 3000                      4520
6  2006-01-31                 3152                      5152
7  2007-01-31                 2998                      5128
8  2008-01-31                 3200                      5132
9  2009-01-31                 3325                      5325
10 2010-01-31                 3700                      6700
11 2011-01-31                 3841                      6841
12 2012-01-31                 4000                      6900
13 2013-01-31                 3251                      5251
14 2014-01-31                 3412                      4412
15 2015-01-31                 3214                      4214
16 2016-01-31                 2825                      3885
17 2017-01-31                 3125                      4125
18 2018-01-31                 3752                      4782
19 2019-01-31                 3245                      4235
20 2020-01-31                 3752                      3892
21 2021-01-31                 3584                      4584
22 2022-01-31                 3125                      4125
23 2023-01-31                 3241                      4256


>>> melted_df
    Serie                 Variables  Valor
0    2000       1. Cuenta corriente   2000
1    2001       1. Cuenta corriente   2015
2    2002       1. Cuenta corriente   2400
3    2003       1. Cuenta corriente   2342
4    2004       1. Cuenta corriente   2515
5    2005       1. Cuenta corriente   3000
6    2006       1. Cuenta corriente   3152
7    2007       1. Cuenta corriente   2998
8    2008       1. Cuenta corriente   3200
9    2009       1. Cuenta corriente   3325
10   2010       1. Cuenta corriente   3700
11   2011       1. Cuenta corriente   3841
12   2012       1. Cuenta corriente   4000
13   2013       1. Cuenta corriente   3251
14   2014       1. Cuenta corriente   3412
15   2015       1. Cuenta corriente   3214
16   2016       1. Cuenta corriente   2825
17   2017       1. Cuenta corriente   3125
18   2018       1. Cuenta corriente   3752
19   2019       1. Cuenta corriente   3245
20   2020       1. Cuenta corriente   3752
21   2021       1. Cuenta corriente   3584
22   2022       1. Cuenta corriente   3125
23   2023       1. Cuenta corriente   3241
24   2000  1.03. Bienes y servicios   3251
25   2001  1.03. Bienes y servicios   3245
26   2002  1.03. Bienes y servicios   2752
27   2003  1.03. Bienes y servicios   3025
28   2004  1.03. Bienes y servicios   2715
29   2005  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4520
30   2006  1.03. Bienes y servicios   5152
31   2007  1.03. Bienes y servicios   5128
32   2008  1.03. Bienes y servicios   5132
33   2009  1.03. Bienes y servicios   5325
34   2010  1.03. Bienes y servicios   6700
35   2011  1.03. Bienes y servicios   6841
36   2012  1.03. Bienes y servicios   6900
37   2013  1.03. Bienes y servicios   5251
38   2014  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4412
39   2015  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4214
40   2016  1.03. Bienes y servicios   3885
41   2017  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4125
42   2018  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4782
43   2019  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4235
44   2020  1.03. Bienes y servicios   3892
45   2021  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4584
46   2022  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4125
47   2023  1.03. Bienes y servicios   4256


No conocía yo esto de melt, me parece super útil. Buena respuesta y bien explicada
